# QGIS - Viewshed Analysis - could not broadcast input array

Tags: qgis, error, analysis, viewshed

Whenever I try to make a viewshed analysis with only one point of interest, I get error messages. Is this because my Terrain model (GeoTIFF) is in ETRS UTM33 (EPSG: 28533)? I create a pointshape with on point and then execute "Create Viewpoints", adjust setting and afterwards I start the tool "viewshed". These are my first approaches, so I presume I am failing here big time, but the protocol is a riddle for me...

Here a snip of the protocol

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/info/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\viewshed_raster.py", line 266, in processAlgorithm
matrix_vis = ws.viewshed_raster (analysis_type, pt[id1], dem,
File "C:\Users/info/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\modules\visibility.py", line 163, in viewshed_raster
dem.open_window (point["pix_coord"])
File "C:\Users/info/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\modules\Raster.py", line 350, in open_window
self.window[ slice(*in_slice_y), slice(*in_slice_x)] = \
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2001,3001) into shape (2001,3001)
Execution failed after 22.68 Sekunden
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the cause was that the raster I used had two bands. One band with the actual height information and one empty one. This causes the (2,xxx,xxx) array. I deleted the unused band by with the "Rearrange Bands" Tool from the toolbox. Just select the band you want to use and press run. The new created layer does only contain the band you need (xxx,xxx).